# How to get rid of the "className" attribute in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

My JSX files are full of:

```
<div className="...">...</div>
```

For example:

```
const Page = () => (

  <div className="Page">

    <div className="sideMenu">
      <Route path="/" component={SidemenuMainCont} />
    </div>

    <div className="mainColumn">
      <div className="header">
        <Header />
      </div>
      <div className="section">
        <Route path="/" component={TenCont} />
      </div>
      <div className="footer">
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>

    <AuthLoginModalCont />

  </div>

);
```

This code looks wired because of this. "className" is too long for a repeatedly used attribute. Is there any common practice to get rid of this annoying repeats? Or to make it shorter?

I can make a custom component like this:

```
<Div cl="...">...</Div>
```

But I am interested if there is a common practice for this. Perhaps there is already an alias for the className attributes? Or some other way to set a CSS class name.

**UPDATE**

Thanks, Przemysław Zalewski for an interesting idea. But actually I am using CSS modules. So my code is:

```
import S from "./_.scss";
...
<div className={S.Page}>...</div>
```

And it does not work:

```
<Styled {S.Page}>...</Styled>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Babel plugin for it - e.g. [babel-plugin-react-html-attrs](https://github.com/insin/babel-plugin-react-html-attrs) allows you to use `class` and `for` attributes when working with JSX in React and changes them to the `className` and `htmlFor` properties (JSX attributes are syntax sugar for object literals) React requires when JSX is being transpiled.

Here's the full source for a Babel 6 plugin which would change `cl` attributes to `className` when transpiling:

```
var TRANSLATIONS = {
  'cl': 'className'
}

module.exports = function() {
  return {
    visitor: {
      JSXAttribute: function(node) {
        if (node.node.name.name in TRANSLATIONS) {
          node.node.name.name = TRANSLATIONS[node.node.name.name]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

My actual suggestion is just stick with `className` and you'll get used to it :)

Comment: Why on earth didn't they write this into JSX transpiler to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    class Div extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className={this.props.cl} >
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            );
        }
    };
    export default Div;
```

And use

```
<Div cl="my_class"></Div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a simple `Styled` component for that case that handles all true boolean properties as class names and joins them as a string using [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).

```
class Styled extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { children, tag: Tag = 'div', ...rest } = this.props;
        const [booleans, others] = partition(x => x === true)(rest)

        return (
            <Tag
                className={classNames(booleans)}
                {...others}
            >
                {children}
            </Tag>
        )
    }
}

const Page = () => (
  <Styled Page>

    <Styled sideMenu>
      <Route path="/" component={SidemenuMainCont} />
    </Styled>

    <Styled mainColumn>
      <Styled Header>
        <Header />
      </Styled>
      <Styled section tag="section">
        <Route path="/" component={TenCont} />
      </Styled section>
      <Styled footer tag="footer">
        <Footer />
      </Styled>
    </Styled>

    <AuthLoginModalCont />

  </Styled>
);
```

There is [a slight variation of the idea](https://jsfiddle.net/4m3gws5t/) with the use of `Proxy` object. However, it will break on older JS engines as it cannot be fully polyfilled but allows writing `<styled.MainColumn full-width red>` without declaring MainColumn beforehand and it is more easily debuggable with [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) as full names are preserved.